# Courant–Friedrichs–Lewy condition for planar FTDT

Tags: numerical-methods, finite-differences, numerical-calculus, electromagnetism

Courant–Friedrichs–Lewy condition in FDTD is used to define minimal time step to remain stability of the solution.
The definition of Courant–Friedrichs–Lewy condition in N-dimensional space says, that

$$
dt(\sum^n_{i=1}\frac{u_{x_i}}{\Delta x_i}) \leq C
$$
or
$$
dt \leq \frac{C}{\sum^n_{i=1}\frac{u_{x_i}}{\Delta x_i}}
$$
where $C$ is a constant and $u_{x_i}$ is a magnitude of velocity.

assume $C=1$ and $u_{x_i}=c$ for any $i$, then for 3D solution we have

$$
dt\leq \frac{1}{c\cdot\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{\Delta x}\right)^2+\left(\frac{1}{\Delta y}\right)^2+\left(\frac{1}{\Delta z}\right)^2}}
$$

the same solution I've seen in "Numerical Electromagnetics. The FDTD Method" by Inan U.S., Marshall R.A. in chapter 5.3

but in [original Yee article](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1138693) there is
$$
c\Delta t < \sqrt{(\Delta x)^2+(\Delta y)^2+(\Delta z)^2}
$$
or
$$
\Delta t < \frac{\sqrt{(\Delta x)^2+(\Delta y)^2+(\Delta z)^2}}{c}
$$
equation used.
And I cannot get the reason of that because for, f.e., $\Delta x = 1$ difference between these two equations is about 10 times, but solution still remains stable for $\Delta t=0.4*\Delta t_2$ and results seem to be the same for the same time interval for the both time steps

Comment: I just found this didactic [document](https://www.flexcompute.com/fdtd101/Lecture-7-Time-step-size-and-CFL-condition-in-FDTD/). I don't know if it brings something new for you...

Comment: It seems, that there the first equation is used